# How to use multiple proxy with JMeter

Tags: proxy, jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

I have a load balancer and I want to test the performance of the load balancer. I am using Apache JMeter to test the load balancer. I need to change my IP address so that the client IP is always different. My uni doesn't allow me to add multiple IP addresses (IP spoofing / IP alias).

So, the other option is to use a proxy server. Is there a way to use 2 or more proxy server in JMeter at one go? I can only specify one proxy server at a time at the moment.

Is there a way to turn it around?

Comment: Did you find out an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Server name /IP" configuration in "HTTP Request" sampler. But those IPs should belong to same network. You cant set jmeter with different Geo locations.